# Failed trying to fill a list with Buttons in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to have a `Button` created and displayed on screen for a list.

I had the code that prints the list `"matching"` and it displays the correct list, however when it goes to display the Buttons, only the last item in the list is displayed on screen as a button.

`self.db`, when printed to screen` shows the entire list as Button components, but again, only last one is displayed on screen.

Been searching and trying different things for hours, but can't figure out why it is behaving the way it is.

This is my code:

```
def GatherAndDisplay(self) :
    """grabs the file and loads into memory to display"""

    SearchData = TCT.ReadData("FullProgramTest.csv")
    ntsf = self.ns.get()
    matching = [s for s in SearchData if ntsf in s]

    self.db = []
    for c in matching:
        print(self.db) #just used this to see if the list was being updated 
        self.db.append(tk.Button(self.top2, text = str(c)))
        self.db[-1].grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)
```

Comment: Are you aware that you're putting all of the widgets in the same row and column? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: I was unaware that I was doing that... That would most likely explain why I only see 1 button. Thanks!